# How do I format a number with a variable number of digits in Python?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, number-formatting

Say I wanted to display the number 123 with a variable number of padded zeroes on the front.

For example, if I wanted to display it in 5 digits I would have `digits = 5` giving me:

```
00123
```

If I wanted to display it in 6 digits I would have `digits = 6` giving:

```
000123
```

How would I do this in Python?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is a string method called zfill:

```
>>> '12344'.zfill(10)
0000012344
```

It will pad the left side of the string with zeros to make the string length N (10 in this case).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, I just do '123'.zfill(m) which allows me to use a variable instead of having a predetermined number of digits. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 213):

If you are using it in a formatted string with the `format()` method which is preferred over the older style `''%` formatting

```
>>> 'One hundred and twenty three with three leading zeros {0:06}.'.format(123)
'One hundred and twenty three with three leading zeros 000123.'
```

See
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format
http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

Here is an example with variable width

```
>>> '{num:0{width}}'.format(num=123, width=6)
'000123'
```

You can even specify the fill char as a variable

```
>>> '{num:{fill}{width}}'.format(num=123, fill='0', width=6)
'000123'
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the new format method. It's taking a bit to get used to, but I actually feel it's a bit cleaner than the old `%` style, which feels ironic to me because I used to feel that the `%` style was the cleanest method.

Comment: Unnamed placefolders are also supported (at least in Python 3.4): `"{:{}{}}".format(123, 0, 6)`.

Comment: @CoDEmanX The unnamed placeholders also work in python 2.7 - thanks.

Comment: With the introduction of f-strings in Python 3.6, it is now possible to access previously defined variables without the need for `.format`. Simply prepend an `f` to the string: `f'{num:{fill}{width}}'`. I added an answer with this info.

Answer (score 31):

With [the introduction of formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) ("f-strings" for short) in Python 3.6, it is now possible to access previously defined variables with a briefer syntax:

```
>>> name = "Fred"
>>> f"He said his name is {name}."
'He said his name is Fred.'
```

The examples given by John La Rooy can be written as

```
In [1]: num=123
   ...: fill='0'
   ...: width=6
   ...: f'{num:{fill}{width}}'

Out[1]: '000123'
```

Answer (score 29):

```
'%0*d' % (5, 123)
```

Comment: This is also quite useful for more general cases. This is the old style of formatting isn't it? It's a shame that the old style is being phased out

Comment: What does `*` in `%0*d` mean? I check Python documents. `*` is not in the `format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]`.

Comment: ["Minimum field width (optional). If specified as an '*' (asterisk), the actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the object to convert comes after the minimum field width and optional precision."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is it possible with new-style formatting also?

Answer (score 16):

For those who want to do the same thing with python 3.6+ and [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) this is the solution.

```
width = 20
py, vg = "Python", "Very Good"
print(f"{py:>{width}s} : {vg:>{width}s}")
```

Comment: What is the `s`?

Comment: s means incoming var is to be treated as string

Answer (score 4):

```
print "%03d" % (43)
```

Prints

> 043

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting

```
print '%(#)03d' % {'#': 2}
002
print '%(#)06d' % {'#': 123}
000123
```

More info here: [link text](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html)