# Python way of printing: with 'format' or percent form?

Tags: python, printing, format

In Python there seem to be two different ways of generating formatted output:

```
user = "Alex"
number = 38746
print("%s asked %d questions on stackoverflow.com" % (user, number))
print("{0} asked {1} questions on stackoverflow.com".format(user, number))
```

Is there one way to be preferred over the other? Are they equivalent, what is the difference? What form should be used, especially for Python3?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use the `format` method, especially if you're concerned about Python 3 and the future.  From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations):

> The formatting operations described here are modelled on C's `printf()`
>      syntax.  They only support formatting of certain builtin types.  The
>      use of a binary operator means that care may be needed in order to
>      format tuples and dictionaries correctly.  As the new
>      :ref:`string-formatting` syntax is more flexible and handles tuples and
>      dictionaries naturally, it is recommended for new code.  However, there
>      are no current plans to deprecate `printf`-style formatting.

Comment: New documentation says this about the percent operator: "The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of quirks that lead to a number of common errors ..." but it is **not** deprecated. http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: It's not officially deprecated, but you're encouraged not to use it.

Comment: Related: http://bugs.python.org/issue14123

Comment: Is .format significantly slower than % ?

Comment: From Python 3.6, you can [use f-strings to access previously defined variables](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498): `print(f"{user} asked {number} questions on stackoverflow.com"`

Answer (score 25):

`.format` was introduced in Python2.6

If you need backward compatibility with earlier Python, you should use `%`

For Python3 and newer you should use `.format` for sure

`.format` is more powerful than `%`. Porting `%` to `.format` is easy but the other way round can be non trivial

Comment: how is it more powerful ?

Comment: @yossi Here's one example http://stackoverflow.com/a/3228928/174728. It also lets you do key/index lookups `import sys;"{[version]}".format(vars(sys))`

Comment: how about:
`import sys;"%(version)s" % (vars(sys))`

Comment: @Pax0r: The linked example is `'{num:{fill}{width}}'.format(num=123, fill='0', width=6)`. You can't do this with `%` unless you "double escape" and apply it twice

Comment: '%s' % (str(123).rjust(6, '0'))

Comment: @Sean, that's formatting a string, not a number. If I just manipulate a value into a string someway there is not need for an extra layer of formatting at all. Indeed `'%s'%` adds nothing extra to the string you already created.

Comment: https://ideone.com/FsIZFy

Answer (score 8):

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations) say that the `format` method is preferred for new code. There are currently no plans to remove % formatting, though.

Answer (score 8):

You can use both .No one said % formatting expression is deprecated.However,as stated before the format method call is a tad more powerful.
Also note that the % expressions are bit more concise and easier to code.Try them and see what suits you best

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `logging` module uses `%`-like syntax, so it may be preferred for consistency reasons.