# unittest.mock: asserting partial match for method argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Rubyist writing Python here.  I've got some code that looks kinda like this:

```
result = database.Query('complicated sql with an id: %s' % id)
```

`database.Query` is mocked out, and I want to test that the ID gets injected in correctly without hardcoding the entire SQL statement into my test.  In Ruby/RR, I would have done this:

```
mock(database).query(/#{id}/)
```

But I can't see a way to set up a 'selective mock' like that in unittest.mock, at least without some hairy `side_effect` logic.  So I tried using the regexp in the assertion instead:

```
with patch(database) as MockDatabase:
  instance = MockDatabase.return_value
  ...
  instance.Query.assert_called_once_with(re.compile("%s" % id))
```

But that doesn't work either.  This approach does work, but it's ugly:

```
with patch(database) as MockDatabase:
  instance = MockDatabase.return_value
  ...
  self.assertIn(id, instance.Query.call_args[0][0])
```

Better ideas?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
import mock

class AnyStringWith(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self in other

...
result = database.Query('complicated sql with an id: %s' % id)
database.Query.assert_called_once_with(AnyStringWith(id))
...
```

**Preemptively requires a matching string**

```
def arg_should_contain(x):
    def wrapper(arg):
        assert str(x) in arg, "'%s' does not contain '%s'" % (arg, x)
    return wrapper

...
database.Query = arg_should_contain(id)
result = database.Query('complicated sql with an id: %s' % id)
```

**UPDATE**

Using libraries like [`callee`](https://github.com/Xion/callee), you don't need to implement `AnyStringWith`.

```
from callee import Contains

database.Query.assert_called_once_with(Contains(id))
```

https://callee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/operators.html#callee.operators.Contains

Comment: Not bad...  but is there a way to set up the mock so it preemptively requires a matching string, instead of having to assert afterwards?

Comment: @jpatokal, added another version.

Comment: Looks like your new version is effectively your own implementation of mocking?  Not that that's necessarily wrong, I just continue to be surprised that unittest.mock doesn't do this kind of thing...

Comment: Solution with __eq__ overriding is cool, but relies on "small trick". I wonder if there's any better solution out of the box... but so far this one looks the best.

Comment: that's what we usually do; does anybody know a library that implements a bunch of these? like `AnyStringWith`, `StartsWith`, `OneOf` etc?

Comment: Maybe a little late to the party, but I just published a library that's exactly this :) Hence a shameless plug: https://github.com/Xion/callee

Comment: I would recommend raising AssertionError over returning False from the matchers __eq__ method to allow writing a custom error message

Comment: @tkruse, `wrapper` in `arg_should_contain` use `aasert` which will raise AssertionError.

Comment: not sure how that helps when only using assert_called_once_with

Comment: @tkruse, I suggested `arg_should_contain` as a alternative to `assert_called_once_with` + `AnyStringWith`.

Comment: sure, but sometimes people need to use assert_called..._with(Matcher), and in those cases it is better if the matcher raises an error than returning false. you arg_should_contain solution is fine.

Comment: @tkruse, `__eq_-` is expected to return True / False, not raising an exception. [Python data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Comment: The documentation to which you link does not confirm your claim. It says explicitly "However, these methods can return any value..." And does not forbid exceptions.

Comment: @tkruse, `return` is not `raise` ;)

Comment: The documentation also says: __eq__() and __ne__() are their own reflection. That means a.__eq__(b) = b.__eq__(a). I don't think using Matchers can stay consistent with that requirement anyway.

Comment: @tkruse, Try `AnyStringWith() == 'any-string-you-want'` and `'any-string-you-want' == AnyStringWith()`. (https://ideone.com/EdrISH) Seems I don't get your point.

Comment: Try `AnyStringWith('ny') == AnyStringWith('any')` and inverse

Answer (score 35):

You can just use `unittest.mock.ANY` :)

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, ANY

def foo(some_string):
    print(some_string)

foo = Mock()
foo("bla")
foo.assert_called_with(ANY)
```

As described here - 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#any

Comment: That asserts that something was sent, but doesn't check that the ID made it through.

Comment: you only wrote a longer version of `assert foo.called`

Comment: also works with objects `assert {"foo": "bar"} == {"foo": ANY} # True`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`match_equality`](https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/integration/#module-hamcrest.library.integration.match_equality) from [PyHamcrest library](https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/) to wrap the [`matches_regexp`](https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/text_matchers/#hamcrest.library.text.stringmatches.matches_regexp) matcher from the same library:

```py
from hamcrest.library.integration import match_equality

with patch(database) as MockDatabase:
  instance = MockDatabase.return_value
  ...
  expected_arg = matches_regexp(id)
  instance.Query.assert_called_once_with(match_equality(expected_arg))
```

This method is mentioned also in Python's [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#more-complex-argument-matching) documentation:

> As of version 1.5, the Python testing library PyHamcrest provides similar functionality, that may be useful here, in the form of its equality matcher (hamcrest.library.integration.match_equality).

If you don't want to use PyHamcrest, the documentation linked above also shows how to write a custom matcher by defining a class with an `__eq__` method (as suggested in `falsetru`s answer):

```py
class Matcher:
    def __init__(self, compare, expected):
        self.compare = compare
        self.expected = expected

    def __eq__(self, actual):
        return self.compare(self.expected, actual)

match_foo = Matcher(compare, Foo(1, 2))
mock.assert_called_with(match_foo)
```

You could replace the call to `self.compare` here with your own regex matching and return `False` if none found or raise an `AssertionError` with a descriptive error message of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

[The chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16976500/595305) is absolutely wonderful.

However, the original question seemed to want to match on the basis of a regex. I offer the following, which I would never have been able to devise without falsetru's chosen answer:

```
class AnyStringWithRegex(str):
    def __init__(self, case_insensitive=True):
        self.case_insensitive = case_insensitive
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.case_insensitive:
            return len(re.findall(self.lower(), other.lower(), re.DOTALL)) != 0
        return len(re.findall(self, other, re.DOTALL)) != 0
```

No doubt many variations on this theme are possible. This compares two objects on the basis of specified attributes:

```
class AnyEquivalent():
    # compares two objects on basis of specified attributes
    def __init__(self, compared_object, *attrs):
        self.compared_object = compared_object
        self.attrs = attrs
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        equal_objects = True
        for attr in self.attrs:
            if hasattr(other, attr):
                if getattr(self.compared_object, attr) != getattr(other, attr):
                    equal_objects = False
                    break
            else:
                equal_objects = False
                break
        return equal_objects
```

For example, this fails even when the file is correct (slightly confusingly, as the error message says the `f` values are the same in terms of their `str(f)` output). The explanation being that the two file *objects* are different ones:

```
f = open(FILENAME, 'w')
mock_run.assert_called_once_with(['pip', 'freeze'], stdout=f)
```

But this passes (explicitly comparing only on the basis of the values of the specified 3 attributes):

```
f = open(FILENAME, 'w')
mock_run.assert_called_once_with(['pip', 'freeze'], stdout=AnyEquivalent(f, 'name', 'mode', 'encoding'))
```

Comment: there's always ways to complicate things more than needed

Answer (score -3):

I always write my unit tests so they reflect the 'real world'. I don't really know *what* you want to test except for `the ID gets injected in correctly`.

I don't know what the `database.Query` is supposed to do, but I guess it's supposed to create a query object you can call or pass to a connection later?

The best way you can test this to take a real world example. Doing something simple like checking if the id occurs in the query is too error prone. I often see people wanting to do magic stuff in their unit tests, this **always** leads to problems. Keep your unit tests simple and static. In your case you could do:

```
class QueryTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_insert_id_simple(self):
        expected = 'a simple query with an id: 2'
        query = database.Query('a simple query with an id: %s' % 2)
        self.assertEqual(query, expected)

    def test_insert_id_complex(self):
        expected = 'some complex query with an id: 6'
        query = database.Query('some complex query with an id: %s' 6)
        self.assertEqual(query, expected)
```

If `database.Query` directly executes a query in the database, you might want to consider using something like `database.query` or `database.execute` instead. The capital in the `Query` implies you create an object if it's all lowercase it implies you call a function. It's more a naming convention and my opinion, but I'm just throwing it out there. ;-)

If the `database.Query` directly queries you can best patch the method it is calling. For example, if it looks like this:

```
def Query(self, query):
    self.executeSQL(query)
    return query
```

You can use `mock.patch` to prevent the unit test from going to the database:

```
@mock.patch('database.executeSQL')
def test_insert_id_simple(self, mck):
    expected = 'a simple query with an id: 2'
    query = database.Query('a simple query with an id: %s' % 2)
    self.assertEqual(query, expected)
```

As an extra tip, try to use the `str.format` method. The `%` formatting may go away in the future. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382719/python-way-of-printing-with-format-or-percent-form) for more info.

I also cannot help but feel testing string formatting is redundant. If `'test %s' % 'test'` doesn't work it would mean something is wrong with Python. It would only make sense if you wanted to test custom query building. e.g. inserting strings should be quoted, numbers shouldn't, escape special characters, etc.

Comment: This is a unit test, not an integration test: I care that the ID has been passed into the method call correctly.  (The sample has been simplified, there's more than just a string substitution going on in the real thing.)  What the called method does internally does not belong at this level of test, and (IMHO) it's bad form to start patching implementation details of other libraries -- if I want a 'real world' test, I'll write an integration test that goes through the whole stack and doesn't mock out bits in the middle.