# How to pass variable inside find_element_by_css_selector method in Selenium , Python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to do some changes in below line :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p[title=\"sanityapp5\"]").click()
```

Now I have create a string variable appname

```
appname="sanityapp5"
```

Now I want to know how to replace sanityapp5 with variable appname in above selenium command.
I am new to python so do know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p[title=\"%s\"]" % appname).click()`

or using the newer style string formatting:

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p[title=\{}\"]".format(appname)).click()`

Comment: how to provide the variable if it is delcared in one python file. Importing that and using inside function

Comment: Is this correct

        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p[title=\"{0}\"]".format(config.appname)).click()

Comment: while providing above line, it throws invalid element state error

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it in a more Pythonic way. Use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) function.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "hello world{}".format("end")
'hello worldend'
>>> "hello world {1} and {0}".format("a", "b")
'hello world b and a'
>>>
```

And it is in your case

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p[title=\"{0}\"]".format(appname)).click()
>>> appname="sanityapp5"
>>> "p[title=\"{0}\"]".format(appname)
'p[title="sanityapp5"]'
```

Few [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382719/python-way-of-printing-with-format-or-percent-form) why you prefer format to percentage.