# Using find function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, find

I would like to solve this problem using the find function. I have been working on it using the split function because I don't understand find. If someone could show me how to do it with find, it would be awesome. Also I am getting stuck in this one part of the problem.

```
start = ("Please enter the starting weight of food (in lbs:ozs) = ")
answerOne = input(start).strip()
startPounds, startOunces = answerOne.split(":")
startPounds = int(startPounds)
startOunces = int(startOunces)
end = "Please enter the ending weight of food (in lbs:ozs) = "
answerTwo = input(end).strip()
endPounds, endOunces = answerTwo.split(":")
endPounds = int(endPounds)
endOunces = int(endOunces)
startPoundsO = startPounds * 16
endPoundsO = endPounds * 16
poundsO = startPoundsO - endPoundsO
```

This is where I am having problems.

**Heres the original problem.**

A monkey is being fed some food. Read in the starting weight in lbs:ozs. Also read in the ending weight in lbs:ozs (you may assume this is smaller than the starting weight. Find the difference and print out the amount of food consumed by the monkey in lbs:ozs.

Heres the data provided.

Starting weight of food (in lbs:ozs)=8:9

Ending weight of food (in lbs:ozs)=6:14

Food consumed by the monkey (lbs:ozs)=1:11

Comment: `split` is perfect for this. Using `find` for this would be like using wire cutters to prepare lettuce. You can do it, but it's awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Amadan, little bit awkward :

```
startPounds, endsPounds = int(answer[0:answer.find(':')]), int(answer[answer.find(':')+1:len(answer)])
```

Comment: finally got everything to work but whats wrong with my Output, cant get it to print correctly.
print (pounds),":",(ounces)

Comment: print (pounds),":",(ounces)

Comment: You can use `print("Result = %d:%d" % (pounds, ounces))` for output

Comment: better to use format - rather than % in my opinion.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Thank you, I didn't notice that OP put python-3.x tag. @CharlesTaylor please revise to `print("Result = {0}:{1}".format(pounds, ounces))` and as reference [**python way of printing: With 'format' or percent form?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382719/python-way-of-printing-with-format-or-percent-form)