# Python os.system works inline but not as a variable

Tags: python, email, xmpp, google-hangouts

This function sends a google hangouts message to the recipient in the EMAIL variable.

It works in the following case where the email in inline with no quotes.

```
import os
EMAIL='in06khattab@gmail.com'

os.system('sudo echo "jjj" | sendxmpp -v -t in06khattab@gmail.com') #send hangouts message
```

However, when I insert the variable in its place, it doesn't send. There are no error message and the debug appears to be sending correctly, but I think it is sending to 'in06khattab@gmail.com' rather than in06khattab@gmail.com. So it may be including the quotes,

```
os.system('sudo echo "jjj" | sendxmpp -v -t EMAIL') #send hangouts message
```

Comment: You should really use subprocess

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Without a link to the module, I doubt the OP knows what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python won't interpret variables in a string like that.

Use concatenation:

```
os.system('sudo echo "jjj" | sendxmpp -v -t ' + EMAIL)
```

Or string formatting:

```
os.system('sudo echo "jjj" | sendxmpp -v -t %s' % EMAIL)
```

Answer (score 2):

For forwards compatibility and readability, I would suggest using `format` to substitute in the `EMAIL` variable.

`os.system('sudo echo "jjj" | sendxmpp -v -t {email}'.format(email=EMAIL))`

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12382738/1210229) for why this is preferable to `%` encoding