# Python 3 string formatting with filler more than one character long

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

I am attempting to format a string in such a way, that I can make a repeating sequence of numbers an arbitrary length.

I've been looking at these examples: [How do I format a number with a variable number of digits in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228865/python-how-do-i-format-a-number-with-a-variable-number-of-digits) and [String Formatting in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945749/string-formatting-in-python-3).

Here's what I tried to do:

```
print("{0:{1}{2}d}".format(0, 0, 8))
```

will result in eight pretty 0's all in a row like so: `00000000`
but attempting to change the second argument from 0 to 25

```
print("{0:{1}{2}d}".format(0, 25, 8))
```

Results in an a single 0 that is as far right as it can go in my console instead of `25252525` So I think the issue is using a string with more than one character as filler instead of a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification for string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) goes like this:

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
```

In this case, we're only interested in the `[0][width]` part. `[0]` is an optional parameter which pads numbers with zeros, so you can format `4` as `'004'`.  `[width]` specifies the total width of the field.

When you write:

```
print("{0:{1}{2}d}".format(0, 0, 8))
```

It becomes:

```
print("{0:08d}".format(0))
```

Which is a `0` padded with zeroes up to a length of 8: `00000000`.

However, your other example:

```
print("{0:{1}{2}d}".format(0, 25, 8))
```

Becomes:

```
print("{0:258d}".format(0))
```

Which is a `0` padded with spaces (because there is no `0` in the formatter) up to a length of 258.

I think string formatting is not suited to solve your problem.  You can use other fill characters than `0` (using the `[fill]` option in the formatting spec), but it can't be more than one character.

The simplest way to get what you want is probably this:

```
>>> print((str(25) * 8)[:8])
25252525
```

Comment: Tons of thanks, I was 100% stuck on this for a couple of hours!