# return formatted string with list comprehension in python2.7

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, list-comprehension, nested-loops

Please note this is from a learning exercise for myself to learn OOP. **Please do not tell me to use numpy** because the point of this exercise for me is to learn about creating classes and defining methods (however, if numpy or any other library contains a method that does exactly what I'm asking for then feel free to point me to it so I can see what the code looks like).

I'm using Python2.7 and I would like to return a string that gives me a spaced out matrix with square brackets on each end, like this:

```
[  12 -42 ]
[   3   4 ]
```

I want to return it as a string (rather than print it in place) because I'm overloading the **str** method. I've seen similar questions which helped me get to the point where I am now. But I'm still not sure if what I want to do is entirely possible the way I want to do it.

This was my first attempt using nested for loops:

```
def __str__(self):
    """ Return each entry in the Matrix spaced apart."""
    string_out = ""
    for row in self.matrix:
        string_out += "["
        for num in row:
            string_out += "%4d"%num
        string_out += "]\n"
    return string_out
```

where `self.matrix` is my array that stores the values of the Matrix object I'm working with. In my example instance `self.matrix = [[12,-42],[3,4]]`).

The for loops give me what I want, however I wanted to see if I could do this in a list comprehension way.

This is my attempt so far with list comprehension:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "]\n".join("".join( "{:4}".format(num) for num in row) for row in self.matrix) +"]"
```

This gives me:

```
  12 -42]
   3   4]
```

which is nearly there, but I can't figure out if there's a way to get the square brackets in the front without having them also repeat in between the numbers.

Would someone be able to either help me out, or put me out of my misery by confirming that it's not possible?

Comment: *"put me out of my misery by confirming that it's not possible?"* - sadly, that's absolutely possible! But note that you first have to figure out how much space is needed for each thing, it won't always be four characters.

Comment: Thanks. So what's a good way to replace the 4 in my formatting with a variable? Like if the largest space needed is `max_size`, my thought would be to try `("{:%s}"%max_size).format(num)` but is that too weird-looking?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3228928/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you're pretty close. You only need to alter what you're `join`ing on, and add an additional left bracket at the beginning. How about:

```
return "[" + "]\n[".join("".join( "{:4}".format(num) for num in row) for row in self.matrix) +"]"
```

Which results in:

```
[  12 -42]
[   3   4]
```

Comment: Ha, that was fast and now I'm shaking my head at myself for not seeing it. Thank you!!